# How to implement UISearchBar in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

I cannot find any material for `UISearchBar` in MonoTouch. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the **ContentControls** and the **MonoCatalog** (both versions) [samples from Xamarin's github](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/) uses `UISearchBar`.

Several applications (with sources, e.g. [TweetStation](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation)) also uses it - either directly or by using [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog).